# Correct architecture for scaling a backend

Tags: mysql, django, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I have 3 instance of my django app hosted on Google Compute Engine in 3 different locations around the world. I am autoscaling my app to set up more instances when the cpu is at 70%. I also have a loadbalancer set up to route traffic to a close and functioning instance. This all works fine however what I don't get is how my database is scaled along with my app, in my case I have one mysql instance that stores all the data from all instances but I am not sure how to scale it since I want the same data to be available for all instances. Having only one presents many problems such as high latency for instances accessing it from another part of the world as well as all requests going to this single mysql instance.

How can I better my architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're planning to set up asynchronous replication and carefully divide your code between sync and async requests, you may find it much easier to run your instances in a single region.

While it's easy to run stateless webservers in multiple regions, a solution like MySQL clustering assumes that the database instances are all fairly close together, or commit latency starts to go up. In this case, putting instances in different regions means you'll be contending with speed of light delays of >100ms for every commit. It will probably be faster for any write requests to go to a webserver in your database's region unless you can cleanly partition your data between regions.

If you're particularly concerned about latency, you can have read requests go to a local instance and only route write requests to the central service, but this can be more complicated to set up. If you're doing this, you may want to use a different user and password for the read vs write database connections, and prohibit the read user from being able to do writes. This prevents a number of exciting MySQL failure modes when using statement-level replication when a write accidentally executes against a replica rather than the master.

Comment: One extra improvement to the scenario above is to store all the static assets (images, css, js) in a CDN. In this way, a big part of your website will be stored close to user and will be served faster than waiting for them to be retrieved from your backends.

Answer (score 0):

In a production environment the Database is often stored on different servers which can be load balanced independently. Have you looked into setting up a MySQL Cluster?

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/

Cheers,

ji